# Cannot connect to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I cannot connect to Firebase realtime database. Here is a simple code which will set value of field `message` to `Hello world`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

    myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
}
```

After manually adding project on firebase console I updated:

1. `google-services.json`
2. added `internet PERMISSION`
3. set rules for `public access`
4. added all dependencies in both Project and module `build.gradle`as instructed
5. updated `proguard-rules.pro` as instructed

Double-checked with Firebase Launch Checklist.

After app launch firebase should update the database but it is showing `null`.

Please help if there is anything I'm missing to make it work.

P.S. Project is a simple Hello World project in which i added above snippet and   updated others accordingly and code is compiling and running perfectly.

Comment: Check your security rules. Make sure they are set to true. You can find your security rules on the Firebase console. Go to real time database and click on rules. make sure they are set to true. Both read and write.

Answer (score -1):

on the database tab, in your firebase console, view rules and change them to this

```
{
"rules": {
".read": "auth == null",
".write": "auth == null"
 }
}
```